# How to fix `declared but its value is never read` false positive?

Tags: typescript

I have imported desired module:

```
import ionRangeSlider from 'ion-rangeslider'
```

Then I used it:

```
jQuery('#price_range').ionRangeSlider({
    ...
})
```

But there's this error on import line:

> 'ionRangeSlider' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Why does this error appear? I have just used my imported module.

Comment: It presumably is from the tslint/eslint? Wouldn't `import from 'ion-rangeslider'` work?

Comment: @zerkms somehow `import 'ion-rangeslider'` just worked.

Answer (score 13):

If you can't drop the `import`, then you could disable the warning.

Please note that the error could arise from the typescript compiler or TSLint (if you're using TSLint). Both have almost the same warning.

In this case I think it's from the typescript compiler because of the error number. (6133)

### Typescript

If this is a typescript error then add before the import `// @ts-ignore`, e.g.

```
// @ts-ignore
import ionRangeSlider from 'ion-rangeslider
```

Note this will disable all warning for the import line. This needs typescript 2.6+

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html

### TSLint

If you're using TSLint, which could give the same error, you could disable it as follows.

Add a tslint comment to disable the warning. For example:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-variable
import ionRangeSlider from 'ion-rangeslider
```

If you need this for multiple lines, you could drop the "next line", e.g.

```
// tslint:disable:no-unused-variable
```

Recommended then to enable it later in the file:

```
// tslint:enable:no-unused-variable
```

See https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/

Answer (score 1):

So the symbol you are seeing above is a **name** while the symbol you are seeing below is a **property**.  Like if I wrote

```js
const x = { x: 'x' };
```

I have defined a constant variable binding `x` (a *name*) to an object with a mutable property `x`, or you might prefer to say `x.x` to avoid confusion, whose initial value is the string `x`, or you might prefer to say `'x'` to avoid confusion.

The name is naming a variable that is entirely unused. Your lint script considers unused variables to be a code smell and recommends against them. You don't need to bind the result of the library you are using to any sort of name because it does its dark work by mutating the `jQuery` object (that is also a function; all functions are objects).

If you do not like these things happening in secret, they are called “side effects” and removing them is the central goal of “(pure) functional programming.”

Comment: Which is a very nice explanation of _why_ he (and I) get the warning, and technically answers the exact question he asked, but doesn't at all help with the issue brought up in your last sentence! I believe your answer hints that the correct solution is the one the OP found: just use `import` rather than `import ion-rangeslider from...` (because we don't need the name **ion-rangeslider** imported, just the side effects). And yes, it _is_ a code smell. I wish ion-rangeslider didn't work the way it does...